# Ruby - Not getting the Last Modified from my Header

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get the last modified date from a request headers. What's strange is when I make the request from Postman, I see Last-Modified, however from Ruby I don't.

Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
def get_last_date(uri)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.inferred_port)
  http.use_ssl = (uri.scheme == 'https')
  http.start
  begin
    req = Net::HTTP::Head.new(uri.request_uri)
    resp = http.request(req)
    resp.each_capitalized { |key, value| p " - #{key}: #{value}" }
    return DateTime.strptime(resp['Last-Modified'], '%a, %e %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
  ensure
    http.finish
  end
end
```

And here's me seeing it in Postman:

[image]

And this is what I see in my console (i.e. from Ruby):

[image]

Comment: Ahh!
Looks like the issue is `uri.request_uri` there's no uri being passed. It just occured to me what `content-length` is 0

Comment: Another update - I think I've figured out whats happening. The url I'm hitting is actually a php page that loads an image. Urls like https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg work fine.
I guess I'd need to download the entire page i.e. not do a `head`. Does this sound about right? I'm new to Ruby

Comment: Yep, so it works. Basically I had to use `Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)` as I was getting an image from a PHP page